# I need to install Windows on an internal HDD and I only have Mac Computer in the house

Tags: windows-8, mac

My Windows laptop's HDD is dead, so I need to install a Windows on a new drive. I have a MacBook, and 16GB USB. I am trying to burn the Windows ISO into the USB using Disk Utility, but don't know how. Please help me.

Comment: yes. the email is private.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). This program creates a bootable USB from an ISO you have. If that doesn't work, then follow these instructions (this works, but is not always guaranteed and is difficult unless you know what you are doing here)

You can run a Terminal command to put it onto a USB. Run terminal and run the command "diskutil list" without the quotes. Then plugin the USB and run the same command. Notice the new device added to the list. It should be something like /dev/disk2.

When you have determined which device is the USB, run "diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2" for example, again without the quotes (ensure you change which disk you put in that command).

Then, run "sudo dd if=/path/to/my/image.iso of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m" again without quotes. The reason you use rdisk instead of just disk, is it will be much quicker as it is a non-buffered device.